# consumers process all the related messages with a specific key

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to make Kafka consumers process all the messages with the same ID in each partition at once. For example, consider one topic containing all orders with different types and there are multiple consumer instances subscribing to this topic. How can I run consumers to process all the messages in each partition with the same Id? Because when the orders are produced with that Id, although Kafka guarantees that all same IDs go to the same partition, but each partition may contain different orders. I need to process all the similar orders in each partition at once(not one by one) and once in a while(not as soon as a new message arrives).

Comment: If possible you can write all events into a db and run your logic on top of it, rather than over-engineering your consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, you'll need to manually batch your data into "bins per ID", then process those on your own. For example, write each record to a database, group by ID, then iterate/process each batch.

As far as Kafka is concerned, you're required to look at each event "one by one", but this does not require you to "handle them" in that order, unless you care about sequential processing, at least once processing, and in-order offset commits.

There's also no way to get "all unique ids" in any partition without consuming the whole partition end-to-end. You could use Kafka Streams aggregate function to help with this, and punctuate to periodically handle all gathered IDs up to a certain point, as one other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected that there should be no way for this, I just wasn't sure. 
I'm going to do that, to accumulate all the messages in a list or dict, and then group them based on the ID and process them. This might not become super fast, though. 
I also thought of kafka streams and ksqldb, but I just wanted to make sure that it cannot be done with pure kafka.

Comment: The main problem with grouping anything is if the process crashes in the middle of a group and auto-commits are enabled. Then you miss a batch of offsets